# Flutter FCM with Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Using Laravel for my App backend and want to send push notification to my flutter app by topic. Now I implemented firebase messaging into my flutter app. as

```
_registerOnFirebase() {
_firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) => print(token));
 }

void getMessage() {
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('received message');

    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print('on resume $message');

}, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print('on launch $message');

});
}
```

and I am sending the notification to the app by Postman and It's working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5p6c.png)
Now please tell me How can I send the notification from my Laravel Forms(From Views Directory).
I have created a controller Named PushNotification and a views directory in the resource directory as (\resources\views\notification\create.blade).

Comment: Could you please share your code currently I'm facing similar problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the controller setup then it won't be that tough to send notification from the frontend/views. Here is my complete example.

1. Create a form in your view form.blade.php file (resources/views/form.blade.php)

   ```
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('bulksend')}}">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" hint="Title" name="title">
        <br>
        <label>Body</label>
        <input type="text" hint="Body" name="body">
        <br>
        <label>Image URL</label>
        <input type="text" hint="Image URL" name="img">
        <br>
        <label>ID</label>
        <input type="text" hint="Image URL" name="id">
        <br>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
   ```
2. Create a web route (routes/web.php)

   ```
    Route::get('form', function () {
        return view('form');
    });

    Route::post('send','MyController@bulksend')->name('bulksend');
   ```
3. Create a controller named MyController in app/Http/Controller and add this function to it.

   ```
    public function bulksend(Request $req){
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $dataArr = array('click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', 'id' => $req->id,'status'=>"done");
        $notification = array('title' =>$req->title, 'text' => $req->body, 'image'=> $req->img, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1',);
        $arrayToSend = array('to' => "/topics/all", 'notification' => $notification, 'data' => $dataArr, 'priority'=>'high');
        $fields = json_encode ($arrayToSend);
        $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "YOUR_FCM_KEY",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

        $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
        //var_dump($result);
        curl_close ( $ch );
        return $result;

    }
   ```

Comment: Thankyou so much for answering. please tell me what is id in form.blade.php file.

Comment: It is the ID that you are going to pass with your notification payload. You can make that constant if you don't want to pass that. Just replace $res->id with any value in bulksend function.

Comment: Thank You so much for providing example.It is working as I needed.

Comment: @AnubhavAnand I used your code but curl seems to not work is there a library or something I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

We do this in Jobs. I share our server side code. you can arrange according to your need.

```
    class SendFCM implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $FcmLog;
    protected $regids;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token,$payload,$incident_action_id=0)
    {
        $FcmLog = new FcmLog();
        $FcmLog->incident_action_id = $incident_action_id;
        $FcmLog->user_fcm_token_ids = $token->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $FcmLog->payload = $payload;
        $FcmLog->response = '';
        $FcmLog->save();

        $this->regids = $token->pluck('token')->toArray();
        $this->FcmLog = $FcmLog;

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        try {
            $regids = UserFcmToken::whereIn('id',$this->FcmLog->user_fcm_token_ids)->get();

            $targets = [
                'android' => [],
                'ios' => []
            ];

            foreach($regids as $regid) {

                $identifier = $regid->device_info['os'];
                if($regid->device_info['os']==='android'&&$regid->device_info['framework']==='flutter') {
                    $identifier = 'android_flutter';
                }
                $targets[$identifier][] = $regid->token;
            }


            $headers = array(
                'Authorization'=>'key = ******YOUR FIREBASE KEY*****',
                'Content-Type'=>'application/json'
            );

            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/',
                'timeout' => 30,
                'connect_timeout' => 15,
                'headers' => $headers
            ]);

            $response = [
                'ios'=>null,
                'android'=>null,
                'android_flutter'=>null
            ];

            if(!empty($targets['ios'])) {
                if ($this->FcmLog->payload['notification_type'] == 'incident_action') {
                    $incident = new Incident();
                    $incidents = $incident->ofUser([
                        'request' => (object) [
                            'resource' => 'pending',
                            'count' => 10,
                            'internal_user_id' => $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['user_id']
                        ]
                    ]);
                    $badgeCount = intval($incidents['total']) ?: 1;
                }
                $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids' => $targets['ios'],
                    'notification' => []
                );

                if($this->FcmLog->payload['notification_type']=='announcement') {
                    $fields['notification'] = [
                        'body'=> $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['announcement']['text'],
                        'title'=> $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['announcement']['title'],
                        'sound'=> "default",
                        'badge'=> $badgeCount,
                        'id'=> $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['announcement']['id'],
                    ];
                } else {
                    $fields['notification'] = [
                        'body'=> $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['message'],
                        'title'=> 'Bildirim!',
                        'sound'=> "default",
                        'badge'=> $badgeCount,
                        'notification_type'=>$this->FcmLog->payload['notification_type'],
                        'id'=> $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['incident_number'],
                        'token'=> $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['public_token'],
                    ];
                }

                $request = $client->post('fcm/send', [
                    'body' => json_encode($fields),
                ]);

                $response['ios'] = (string) $request->getBody();

            }

            if(!empty($targets['android'])) {

                $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids' => $targets['android'],
                    'data' => $this->FcmLog->payload
                );

                $request = $client->post('fcm/send', [
                    'body' => json_encode($fields),
                ]);

                $response['android'] = (string) $request->getBody();

            }
            if(!empty($targets['android_flutter'])) {

                if($this->FcmLog->payload['notification_type']=='announcement') {
                    $notificationBody = $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['announcement']['text'];
                    $notificationTitle = $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['announcement']['title'];
                } else {
                    $notificationBody = $this->FcmLog->payload['notification_body']['message'];
                    $notificationTitle = 'Bildirim!';
                }

                $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids' => $targets['android_flutter'],
                    'data' => $this->FcmLog->payload,
                    'notification' =>  [
                        'body'=>$notificationBody,
                        'title'=>$notificationTitle
                    ]
                );
                $fields['data']['click_action'] = 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK';

                $request = $client->post('fcm/send', [
                    'body' => json_encode($fields),
                ]);

                $response['android_flutter'] = (string) $request->getBody();

            }

        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = [ mb_substr($e->getMessage(),0,200) ];
        }

        $this->FcmLog->response = $response;
        $this->FcmLog->save();
    }
}
```